# 2 text files comparison and identify type of mismatches

Tags: perl, comparison

I have this code which compare two sample text files and report any numeric mismatch.

Text1:

```
C_A C_A 0.0000 0.0000 0 0 50 47 100 390
C_A/I0/I2 INV 1.0400 0.2210 0 0 530 200 250 261
C_A/I0/I0 INV 0.0200 0.2210 0 0 20 200 30 100
```

Text2:

```
C_A C_A 0.0000 0 0 0 50 47 100 390
C_A/I0/I0 INV 0.0200 0.2213 0 0 20 200 40 100
C_A/I0/I2 INV 1.00 0.2210 1 1 535 200.00 250 261
```

code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %ref_data;

open my $fh, '<', 'Text1' or die "Could not open to read: $!";
while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  my ( $occurname, $tempname, @data1) = split;
  $ref_data{$occurname} = \@data1;
}

open $fh, '<', 'Text2' or die "Could not open to read: $!";
while (<$fh>) {
  my ( $occurname, $tempname, @data2 ) = split;
  my $data1 = $ref_data{$occurname};

  for ( 0 .. $#data2 ) {
    if ( $data1->[$_] != $data2[$_] ) { 
      print "$occurname $tempname has mismatch property\n";
      last;
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
C_A/I0/I0 INV has mismatch property 
C_A/I0/I2 INV has mismatch property
```

I would like to enhance my code which the content of @data in below sequence `($x_os $y_os $reflection $rotation @nodes)` are output along with error message to ease user for debugging.

Desired Output:

```
C_A/I0/I0 INV has mismatch property (y_os,nodes)
C_A/I0/I2 INV has mismatch property (x_os,reflection,rotation,nodes)
```

Comment: The variables `$x_os`, `$y_os`, `$reflection`, `$rotation`, and `@nodes` don't appear in your code, and there is no evidence of what you mean  them to be. While I could guess your intention, it would be much easier if you explained it yourself. The `@data` arrays contain eight numbers. Are you saying the first four are `$x_os`, `$y_os`, `$reflection`, and `$rotation`, and the trailing four corespond to `@nodes`?

Comment: yes, you are right. The variables are represent the contents of @data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the meaning that I assumed gives the output that you require, I am posting this solution.

The main difference is that, instead of printing a message and moving on to the next hash element as soon as *any* difference is found, it compares *all* of the fields and pushes the name of any differing field on array `@diffs`. The message is printed after *all* the comparisons have been made if `@diffs` isn't empty.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %ref_data;

open my $fh, '<', 'Text1' or die "Could not open to read: $!";
while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  my ( $occurname, $tempname, @data1) = split;
  $ref_data{$occurname} = \@data1;
}

my @fields = qw/ x_os y_os reflection rotation /;

open $fh, '<', 'Text2' or die "Could not open to read: $!";
while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  my ( $occurname, $tempname, @data2 ) = split;
  my $data1 = $ref_data{$occurname};

  my @diffs;

  for my $i ( 0 .. $#data2 ) {
    if ( $data1->[$i] != $data2[$i] ) {
      if ($i < 4) {
        push @diffs, $fields[$i];
      }
      else {
        push @diffs, 'nodes';
        last;
      }
    }
  }

  printf "%s %s has mismatch property (%s)\n", $occurname, $tempname, join(', ', @diffs) if @diffs;
}
```

**output**

```
C_A/I0/I0 INV has mismatch property (y_os, nodes)
C_A/I0/I2 INV has mismatch property (x_os, reflection, rotation, nodes)
```

Comment: Appreciate your effort. Thanks for quick reply and tips. It works fine.