# calling shift method inside a string perl

Tags: perl, string-concatenation

Is there any way we can do something to achieve something like this:

```
$str .= "some content shift(arr) some_other_content"
```

basically I want to call shift on a array without declaring any other variable and concat the value to the middle of string. The shorter the code the better.

I have tried something like this and it worked:

```
$str .= (("some_content" . shift(arr)) . "some_other_content");
```

but is there anything more cleaner or elegant(without bracket). It is not a very big deal but I was just curious.

Comment: Why? I hope I don't have to maintain your code !

Comment: @justintime I am learning perl. In fact I have only written about 100 lines of code in perl till now and this is my first assignment. I was curious if this could be done. hence the question.
Apart from that, I would appreciate your concern if you suggest a solution or a reason for you opinion.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr = qw/ and even /;
my $str = "This is ";

$str .= "some content @{[shift @arr]} some_other_content.";

print $str;
```

Output:

```
This is some content and some_other_content.
```

It's the [baby cart](http://search.cpan.org/~book/perlsecret-1.004/lib/perlsecret.pod#Baby_cart_@%7B%5B_%5D%7D).

Comment: @Borodin - I know, but I couldn't resist.

Comment: Another possibility is: `$str .= "some content ${\ shift @arr } some_other_content.";`. This is a scalar deref containing a reference to the result of an expression. (Similar idea to the baby cart which is an array deref containing an anonymous array, containing the result of an expression.)

Answer (score 3):

Perl isn't as neat as Ruby here, and a lot depends on the context, but you can write

```
$str .= sprintf "some content %s some_other_content", shift @arr
```

Does that help?

Comment: @Kenosis: I spray `sprintf` around wherever it helps!

Comment: Actually, I noticed that in [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673462/2-text-files-comparison-and-identify-type-of-mismatches/20673962#20673962) (`printf`) you provided.  I took note...

Comment: @Kenosis: Oh dear. I am no mentor, but I'm pleased if it helped

Answer (score 2):

Expressions are never evaluated inside quoted strings, you have to use concatenation. But you don't need the parentheses, the default precedence works for this expression.

```
$str .= "some content" . shift(@arr) . "some_other_content";
```

Comment: I tried this: `$str .= "some content" . shift @arr . "some_other_content";` and this gave error. hence added brackets. 
Can you explain the minute difference

Comment: @aman That will be the same as `shift(@arr . "some_other_content")`. `@arr` will be the number of elements in the array.